# How to loop a video seamlessly in Android Studio

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, video, android-mediaplayer

I'm currently creating a fitniss app in Android studio and for every exercise
there is a video loop playing in a VideoView

Now my problem is that the loop is not seamless there is a short break after every play. The videos cant be local because the app would get to big for the playstore

My Code in Kotlin:

```
private fun setExerciseVideo(){
    vvVideo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(exerciseList![currentExercisePosition+1].getVideo())
       
    vvVideo.setVideoURI(uri)
    vvVideo.start()
    vvVideo.setOnPreparedListener {
        mMediaPlayer = it
        mMediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks good, but the issue might be the order the code is executed.

What happens if you move  `.setVideoURI(uri)` `.start()` **after** the `setOnPreparedListener`?

If the suggestion above does not work you can try this also:

```
 val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(exerciseList![currentExercisePosition+1].getVideo())
   
 vvVideo.setVideoURI(uri)
 vvVideo.setOnPreparedListener {

      mMediaPlayer = it
      mMediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
      mMediaPlayer!!.start()
        
 }
```

Comment: Is there no way of detecting video's `current time` and `total time`? For seamless looping the Asker could try using a timer to check the current video time and simply **seek to** zero time whenever the video time is equal to its total time. Waiting for some `videoEnded` type events to trigger is what causes momentary pause in looping. Just **seek** back to the start when you need a loop effect to happen.